# GetEvent<>.Subscribe of event aggregator gives exception

Tags: c#, prism, eventaggregator

I am loading the dll's using reflection and I then try to execute a method in that dll. That method has this line that subscribes to an event. I get an exception at this line

This line is in a dll that I am invoking dynamically using reflection

```
evntAgg.GetEvent<ExceptionEvent>().Subscribe(Message);
```

and the exception is something like this:

> The Target of the IDelegateReference should be of type System.Action`1[[CustomType, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].
>       Parameter name: actionReference

this is the event handling method and is in the same dll that I am invoking dynamically

```
public void Message(ExceptionEvent exception)
{
//Do something
}
```

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: I forgot to mention your username in the comment to my answer, so not sure if you got notified - just in case you weren't: Please read my answer again, the `Message`-method should has `TEventArgs` as parameter, not `TEvent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Prism's `EventAggregator`-class you will need to fulfill vertain requirements:

1. Define an event that derives from `CompositePresentationEvent<TEventArgs>`, where `TEventArgs` derives from `System.EventArgs`
2. Define a **public** method that handles your event, taking an instance of `TEventArgs` as parameter; for example:

   ```
   public void HandleExceptionEvent(ExceptionEventArgs eventArgs)
   {
   }
   ```

   The method needs to be public because otherwise the `EventAggregator` won't be able to invoke that method.
3. Subscribe to your event:

   ```
   evntAgg.GetEvent<ExceptionEvent>.Subscribe(HandleExceptionEvent);
   ```

   Given that you have implemented step 2 as described that should work without a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Implementation is as  described by you. The methods is public, but I still get the same exception

Comment: Please note that I am invoking the method from a dll dynamically using reflection. Is thee anything else that I need to take care of?

Comment: Which method are you invoking dynamically? The method handling your event? Please describe that scenario in more detail in your question, also showing the relevant code parts, especially the method handling the event.

Comment: @Virus Please read my post carefully: The handler needs an argument of type **TEventArgs** not **TEvent**.

Comment: Thanks for response. Got the solution. The event class was in different dll and I was not loading that dll.